# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I am installing eclipse in my mac and just try to test this code but show the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" How i can solv or fixed it?

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the name of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse select this menu: **Run** > **Run Configurations...**

[image]

Then select the Run configuration of your test code.

[image]

In the *Main class* field check what's written there...
If the class `MyMain` has no package, *Main class* field should contain "MyMain".

Comment: @RzRasel Check the pictures I have added

Answer (score 0):

This class should compile and work if the file is called MyMain.java.
to compile it just run `javac MyMain` from the same directory the file is located. Then run `java MyMain` and you are good.